# Does Memory in Use segment in SVMON output has direct impact with system core generation?

Tags: java, jvm, aix

From svmon output i could see the memory in use is 16GB but when generation of system core using user event generated core dump of 3GB why  discrepancy in the system core generation with respect to SVMON output value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple reason the above things could happened
1) If the Disk space is limited or not enough to dump the memory page information, it will lead to truncated or limited system core.
2) If the soft limit or Hard limited are set to specified value then
it lead to generate truncated or limited system core.